# How are tertiary protein structures represented in computers?

Tags: proteins

What data structure is used in representing protein structures in computers so that we can apply algorithms?

Matrix or Graph or tree?

**P.S.** I am absolutely new to Bioinformatics.

Comment: +1. Welcome to MMSE! Close voters: The question has been answered and the OP has accepted it. Please see this: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/228/5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't specify what the algorithms shall do.  If *represented* does not equal to *visualization*, then a the structures may be stored, transferred and processed *via* the atomic coordinates of the protein.  For proteins, the [.pdb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protein_Data_Bank_(file_format)) format is quite common.  After a header, the (x,y,z) are described in a block like

```
ATOM      1  N   PRO A   1       8.316  21.206  21.530  1.00 17.44           N
ATOM      2  CA  PRO A   1       7.608  20.729  20.336  1.00 17.44           C
ATOM      3  C   PRO A   1       8.487  20.707  19.092  1.00 17.44           C
ATOM      4  O   PRO A   1       9.466  21.457  19.005  1.00 17.44           O
ATOM      5  CB  PRO A   1       6.460  21.723  20.211  1.00 22.26           C
```

(*loc. cit.*)

in the first three columns with entries of type *real* (not *integer*, nor *character*) with the implicit unit of Angstrom (i.e., $\pu{10^{-10} m}$).  Note that the format equally supports `D` instead of `H` to describe the deuterium isotope ([reference](http://wiki.jmol.org/index.php/File_formats/Coordinates#PDB)).  If you need to familiarize yourself with this file fomat, visit e.g., Jmol's public set of reference files [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmol/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/Jmol-datafiles/pdb/).

If the algorithms are about determining *similarity* between molecules stored in a database, then likely [fingerprints](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Fingerprints/intro.html) are more suitable for you.

Comment: This does not really explain how the "tertiary" part of tertiary protein structure is represented. In other words, even if I have a snapshot of a protein structure in terms of Cartesian coordinates, what does that tell me about the *persistence* of atomic contacts?

Comment: I'm pretty sure pdb uses residue definitions to specify covalent connections between atoms. Those definition files give meaning to the third and fourth columns, eg CA PRO means the alpha carbon of a proline structure.